# Any reason why this javascript blink code won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code in the second of two js files from a web-app.

It works fine, until I combine the two js files into one. Then the js breaks.

```
function oBlink()
{ 
return window.setInterval
( 
    function()
    {
        $("#sOr").css("background-color", function (){ this.switch = !this.switch; return this.switch ? "#F90" : ""  });    
    }
    , 500 
);
}
```

I've isolated the problem to the code

```
this.switch = !this.switch; return this.switch ? "#F90" : ""
```

If I take that out, the rest of my js works fine.

I understand there are a lot of external variables that could be coming into play here, but I just wanted to check with you guys that the above function code doesn't have any errors in it.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Check the browser console for debugging.

Comment: I forgot to mention - it's working fine in the browser, but failing when checking it on certain devices in the Android emulator. When I take that line out, it works fine in the emulator.

Comment: What do you mean by "js breaks"? No response? Unexpected output? Or something else?

Comment: Things freeze up - eg js driven drop down menu won't work, jquery display elements aren't displaying correctly.

Comment: Just to let you know, `switch` is a reserved word in JavaScript, as it is in many other languages as well. Although, you can get away with it because you're using it as a property of an object, you should think twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's working fine in the browser, but failing when checking it on certain devices in the Android emulator.

That's probably because you are using `switch` in your code which is a reserved word in JavaScript. Only ECMAScript5-based browsers allow using [reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) as object's properties.

Instead of using a flag you can declare a CSS class and use the jQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you define somewhere

> `switch = false`

Then Try

> $("#sOr").css("background-color", function (){ this.switch =
>   !this.switch; return (this.switch ? "#F90" : "#FFF" ) });

Comment: This is not needed - he sets `this.switch = !this.switch' - the not would automatically negate the undefined from the object and result in a true. See @undefined's answer.

Comment: But if switch is not defined at all, then the entire script becomes unresponsive.